# how to setup self relation with same table in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am using Yii 1.x version.

I am stuck while setting up a relation with same table using two different model. my scenario is something like this.

1. There are two tables, user and user_friend_list
2. Two different model for each table User & UserFriendList.

Following are the fields for my table.

**User:** `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`.
**UserFriendList:** `id`, `user_id`, `friend_user_id`

I want to set up relation between two model so that i can fetch all friend information of any user. Kindly suggest me what would be best approach to achieve this???

Note: 
The User table stores user information.
User Friend List table store friend list of user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

In `User` model -

```
'friends' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserFriendList', 'user_id'),
```

In `UserFriendList` model -

```
'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. my exact requirement was found here.. http://bit.ly/1lCmDWz

Answer (score 0):

Two tables - user & friends

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friend` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `friend_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `friend_user_id` (`friend_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

--

```
ALTER TABLE `friend`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `friend_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`friend_user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `friend_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`);
```

Relations I have in my user model

```
return array(
        'friends' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Friend', 'friend_user_id'),
        'friends1' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Friend', 'user_id'),
);
```

And friend model

```
return array(
        'friendUser' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'friend_user_id'),
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
);
```

I hope this helps. I found it on yiiforum